# how to count number of Project

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in mysql. The database contain three table such as "scheme","project","scheme_project. the main entities are scheme , project and i am using the scheme_project to make "Many to Many" relation between scheme and project.the following are tables field and data

```
------scheme----------------------
schemeid    scheme_name    
   1         DWSS
   2         Food and sec
   3         DRM
   4         VST
------------------------------------
```

another table

```
-------project----------------------
projectid    project_name
   1          WASH
   2          WHH
   3          SSS
------------------------------------
```

another table

```
----------scheme_project------------

id      scheme_id        projectid

1           1               2
2           1               1
3           2               1
4           3               2
5           4               1
------------------------------------
```

So now i need a query to find the total number of project for all scheme.
i have probleum when i count projectid it show me 5 but actually the projects are 2 in this case.
anyone help please.

Comment: Please edit your question and proper the format, not getting anything....

Comment: Why not using the `scheme_project` table for that purpose? Just count the amount of unique values for `projectid` field, no? (instead of having a `join` query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use distinct

> select count(distinct projectid) from yourtable

Comment: it is working in my case. thanx a lot @Siddhu siddhartha roy and all friends who pay attention to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by projectid` as below

```
select scheme_id, count(*) as total_projects 
from scheme_project
group by projectid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total,p.project_name, s.scheme_name FROM scheme s
INNER JOIN scheme_project ON sp.scheme_id = s.schemeid
INNER JOIN project p ON p.projectid = sp.projectid
GROUP BY p.project_name, s.scheme_name
```

This will return you how many `projects` listed in a `scheme`.